# Colab: Unable to access webpage using flask-ngrok

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory, web-deployment, web-development-server

I'm trying to run flask application on colab but I keep seeing the following when I go to the tunneled page:-

[image]

Code:-

```py
# flask_ngrok_example.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)  # Start ngrok when app is run

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Did you install your AuthToken and restart the agent as noted at the bottom of the image?

Answer (score 3):

On Colab, you can run these commands:

```python
!pip install pyngrok==4.1.1
!ngrok authtoken 'your authtoken'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To not render to `ngrok-signup` page when using `flask-ngrok` you should authenticate the `ngrok` from your local-machine using your authentication token from [ngrok website](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken).

First install dependencies.

```bash
pip install flask-ngrok
pip install pyngrok==4.1.1
```

Authenticate with `ngrok` with your token

```bash
!ngrok authtoken <ngrok-token>
```

Now you can write your code as sample below:

```py
# flask_ngrok_example.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)  # Start ngrok when app is run

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```